# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter blinks my row when it's updated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase to create a chat app. I'm using a `recycleView` and `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` from firebase-ui to display all messages. My problem is when someone like a message (as you can see below) the entire layout blinks. It happens if I change the message on Firebase Console as well. In my view holder I only update the heart image view according with my model. I'm using version 0.6.2 but it still happens on 1.0.0.

About my adapter, I extend `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and because I'm using `viewTypes` I've overridden the following methods:

- getItemViewType
- populateViewHolder
- onCreateViewHolder

[image]

```
class ChatMessageOutViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.message_out_content)
    TextView messengerView;

    @BindView(R.id.message_out_heart)
    ImageView heartView;

    @BindView(R.id.message_out_heart_likes)
    TextView likesView;

    @BindView(R.id.message_out_time)
    TextView timeView;

    ChatMessageOutViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
    }

    void apply(final ChatMessage model) {
        messengerView.setText(model.content);
        likesView.setText(model.likes == null ? "" : String.valueOf(model.likes.size()));

        Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_fav_1);
        if (model.likes != null && model.likes.contains(mUserId)) {
            image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_fav_2);
        }

        heartView.setImageDrawable(image);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        timeView.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(model.getTimeStamp())));

        heartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onHeartClick(model);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out!! It's not a bug on FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. It's sounds like a default behaviour of RecyclerView. To solve it a just add the following lines after setup my local reference.

```
RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator();
if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
    ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
}
```